# Android: Unable to play video from private path subdirectory using intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent, memory

I am able to play video from private path /data/data/com.exmaple.ui/files/final.mp4 this path.

But unable to play from **subdirectory** like /data/data/com.exmaple.ui/files/myVideos/final.mp4,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File playFile = new File("/data/data/com.exmaple.ui/files/myVideos/final.mp4");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(playFile), "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

**File Creation code:**

```
    String path =  getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    File dest = new File(path,"myVideos");
    boolean mkdirs = dest.mkdirs();
    File destFinal =  new File(dest,"final.mp4");
    destFinal.setReadable(true, false);
    copyFileUsingFileStreams(inputfile,destFinal);
```

**Copy Code:**

```
private void copyFileUsingFileStreams(File source, File dest) throws IOException {

    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;

    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(source);
        output = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
            output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        dest.setReadable(true);
    } finally {
        input.close();
        output.close();
    }
```

Have made file readable,its not allowing me to read the file like above using intents any reason?

**Error :**
Device 1:

```
07-09 14:22:12.098: W/VideoView(17106): Unable to open content: file:///data/data/com.exmaple.ui/files/myVideos/final.mp4
07-09 14:22:12.098: W/VideoView(17106): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
```

Error :Device 2:

```
----------Private File canRead :true Exists :true
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/tcon/tcon/mode: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at com.sec.android.hardware.SecHardwareInterface.sysfsWrite(SecHardwareInterface.java:100)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at com.sec.android.hardware.SecHardwareInterface.setTconUIMode(SecHardwareInterface.java:343)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at com.sec.android.app.videoplayer.activity.MoviePlayer$SecHWInterfaceWrapper.setTconUIMode(MoviePlayer.java:5980)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at com.sec.android.app.videoplayer.activity.MoviePlayer$24.handleMessage(MoviePlayer.java:3644)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
    07-09 20:06:00.636: W/System.err(19371):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-09 20:06:00.646: W/System.err(19371):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    07-09 20:06:00.646: W/System.err(19371):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
    07-09 20:06:00.646: W/System.err(19371):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
    07-09 20:06:00.646: W/System.err(19371):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-09 20:06:00.646: W/System.err(19371): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    07-09 20:06:00.646: W/System.err(19371):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    07-09 20:06:00.646: W/System.err(19371):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    07-09 20:06:00.646: W/System.err(19371):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
    07-09 20:06:00.646: W/System.err(19371):    ... 14 more
```

Wonder how root and subfloder making a difference here? any restrictions mentioned?
File provider or the Content provider are the options?
Thanks
Nitz

Comment: Why have it `internal`, you can copy it to your SD or change the permissions.

Comment: Requirement is to store and play from internal memory

Comment: Most likely a `requirement` from someone who does not understand how Android works.

Comment: @Jared Burrows Seriously? Forget about the requirement..Let me know in general..

Comment: I already answered your question. Read my first comment. or you can try a `FileProvider`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304489/how-to-open-private-files-saved-to-the-internal-storage-using-intent-action-view

Comment: Whats the deal between root and sub-folder? anywhere its mentioned? y is it palying from root folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82972/discussion-between-nitzrobotkoder-and-jared-burrows).

Answer (score -1):

Since you have this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/tcon/tcon/mode: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Means that the file doesn´t exist or you don´t have the correct path to the file.

Use instead:

```
    File playFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/data/com.exmaple.ui/files/myVideos/final.mp4");
    if(playFile.exists()){ 
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(playFile), "video/mp4");
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The file doesn´t exist!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

or

```
    File playFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/data/com.exmaple.ui/files/myVideos", "final.mp4");
    if(playFile.exists()){ 
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(playFile), "video/mp4");
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The file doesn´t exist!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And very important remember to **add the permission**:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: ----------Private File canRead :true Exists :true...my file exists..pls see logs..my requirement is to play from internal memory..

Comment: `/data/data/com.exmaple.ui` is internal storage, not external. The op would need to create it on the SD card first.

Comment: @JaredBurrows what do you mean "The op would need to create it on the SD card first"? Requirement is to store and play from internal memory.

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder You just answered you own question. This post is for the SD card.

Comment: @JaredBurrows check the question.. i am on feasibility test..Question and answer are irrelevant..