# Android: FileProvider IllegalArgumentException Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/**/files/Videos/final.mp4

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I am trying to use `FileProvider` to play a video from private path.Facing

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/XXXXX(Package)/files/Videos/final.mp4
```

Code:

```
<paths>
    <files-path path="my_docs" name="Videos/" />
</paths>
```

Java code:

```
File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "Videos");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "final.mp4");
Log.d(TAG, "-------------newFile:"+newFile.exists());//True here
//Exception in below line
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.wow.fileprovider", newFile);
```

Manifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.wow.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">

<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
```

Any clues on this?

Thanks
Nitz

Comment: I was getting "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix" in @xml/file_paths while implementing Fileprovider..later somehow i ended up misplacing the name and path and ended up with this issue..

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have your `name` and your `path` flipped. `name` is what goes in the `Uri`, and `path` is the relative location within the root on the filesystem.

Go with:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="my_docs" path="Videos/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: Gosh!! Wonder how I misplaced it. You saved my day thanks.. :-)

Comment: Stuck with"java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{44c35948 3239:com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad/u0a307} (pid=3239, uid=10307) that is not exported from uid 10221"  Trying to pass to video player via intent.

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder: If by "video player", you mean a separate app, then add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to your `Intent` that you use with `startActivity()` to launch the player. If by "video player" you mean `MediaPlayer`, I'd go the `FileDescriptor` route rather than a `ContentProvider`. If by "video player" you mean `VideoView`, I have no suggestions.

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Log.d(TAG, "-------------PAth:"+contentUri.getPath());
    intent.setData(contentUri); 
    intent.setType("video/mp4"); Sloved it but getting " Writing exception to parceljava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null"

Comment: Pls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321310/android-unable-to-play-video-from-private-path-subdirectory-using-intent Now taking file provider route.Trying to play using external video players available.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();  
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "video/*");  
    startActivity(intent);
    
    ..Worked setting type and data separate was the issue..

Comment: I forgot the `getFilesDir()`. Another thing to keep on lookout.

Comment: `name` is the parent directory and `path` is the subdirectory. It's confusing how the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#SpecifyFiles) explains it.

Answer (score 11):

change your provider XML to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
  <root-path name="external_files" path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the very same basic situation. I defined everything correctly (files-path in xml) but there is one more thing which leads to the same exception. I add another answer just as an addition and a comment would not be well readable.

I created/read the directory where i store the files like:

```
context.getDir("Documents", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

This leads to a path like:

/data/user/0/ch.myapp/app_Documents/6c3c70d5-af66-48ef-8dfc-f4341de4e1bd.docx

Then i changed creating the directory to:

```
File directory = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "Documents");
if (!directory.exists()) {
  directory.mkdir();
}
```

This leads to a path like:

/data/user/0/ch.myapp/files/Documents/6c3c70d5-af66-48ef-8dfc-f4341de4e1bd.docx

According to the documentation [Open a directory](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#OpenDirInternal) the two methods should be equivalent as far as i understand it. But it creates a different path... Maybe the formulation is just not clear for me in the documentation, but for me its wrongly written.

> getDir(name, mode)
>
> Creates a new directory (or opens an existing directory) within your
>   app's unique file system directory. This new directory appears inside
>   the directory provided by getFilesDir().