# How to get URI for file correctly in Android?

Tags: java, android, image, storage

I am trying to get the URI for a file like this:

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "br.com.[blablabla].sgaconsultor",
                        createImageFile());

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String imageFileName = "registroFoto";

        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        return File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                directory
        );
    }
```

I have a file provider:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="br.com.[blablabla].blabla"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

And the xml is:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="br.com.[blablabla].blabla" path="app_imageDir" />
</paths>
```

But when I run this code I always get this error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Android: FileProvider IllegalArgumentException Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/**/files/Videos/final.mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345275/android-fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-th)

But no luck so far... **So how can I fix this and get the URI for my file?**

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how can I fix this and get the URI for my file?

Step #1: Get rid of the useless stuff in the Java code.

Step #2: Get the Java code and the `file_paths` resource to match, as `file_paths` says that the file path has to be under `getFilesDir()` and have `app_imageDir` in it, and your Java code does not have either of those things.

So, try this:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String imageFileName = "registroFoto";
    File directory = new File(getFilesDir(), "app_imageDir");

    directory.mkdirs();

    return File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            directory
    );
}
```