# Is it possible to develop ppt reader in android

Tags: android

Is any library available for developing the ppt reader or it is possible to develope ppt reader? As I search lots of examples, but I am not able to find anything which is usefull.
Please suggest me how to start? as I have to implement ppt viwer in my app

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for opening the PPT file in other app via Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivity( intent );
```

Otherwise try with **[Aspose.Slides for Android](https://github.com/asposeslides/Aspose_Slides_Android)**

[image]

Comment: In your intent, type shouldn't be "application/ppt"? If not, why?

Comment: @Sipka you can find the Mime type of the file programmatically! see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068648/launching-an-intent-for-file-and-mime-type)

Comment: here is some MIME types list http://androidsbs.blogspot.in/2014/01/intent-settypestring-type-how-to-set.html

Comment: Thanks a lot guys...With using mime type we will open ppt with third party app(e.g. Adobe, Office suite)..Can we do somethig with parent app only?